# why user bash file doesn't work on root in MAC

Tags: bash

I have set some alias on the ~/.bash_profile

like, alias artisan='php artisan' ,
and type: source ~/.bash_profile .
It's ok to execute the "artisan" in the terminal.

But when i changed into Root(type:sudo su) it's not work anymore.
terminal shows that command not found.

And i search some other topic said that there has ./bashrc
and i copy all the things which in my USER bash_profile
to the ./bashrc , and reload it , still doesn't work

Could somebody tell me why i got this problem? Thankyou so much.

Comment: Why not just `su`? and it's `.bashrc`, not `./bashrc`

Comment: i don't why when i use "su" , and type my password , it shows that su:sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sudo -s` instead of `sudo su`. It'll leave more of your regular environment intact, including leaving $HOME set to your regular user home directory instead of the root user's home directory, which means that bash will run the .bashrc from your user home instead of looking for it in the root home.

(And as l'L'l pointed out, it's .bashrc not ./bashrc)

Answer (score 0):

`~/.bashrc` is automatically sourced, because it is in your home directory (`~`).
However when you change to root, your home directory changes as well.
You can test this by typing:

```
$ sudo su
$ echo ~
/var/root
```

And when you think about putting `~/.bashrc` into the root home directory: ***Very bad idea***. Don't mess with that directory. However you can put it into `/etc/bashrc` in which case it will sourced for all users on the system.